# Replacing IPs in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, clearml

I have a nested schema for mongoDB collection. It looks smth like this:

```
{
   "_id":"61d99bf5544f4822bd963bda0a9c213b",
   "execution": {
        "test_split":0,
        "artifacts":{
            "9ed39_output": {
                "uri": "http://100.com/somefile"
            },
            "8d777_output":{
                "uri": "http://100.com/anotherfile"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that artifacts keys are unique. I need to replace the ip stored in uri (in this dummy example "100") with some other ip (lets say "200"). I need to write some `find` and `foreach`. But I am really confused by variable keys under "artifacts". Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Database is part of ClearML. There is an example how to change location for models: https://clear.ml/docs/latest/docs/faq/#relocate_models. But I couldnt succeed adapting that rather simple schema to this usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fully clear how general you like to modify the document. In principle you can do it like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { "execution.artifacts": { $objectToArray: "$execution.artifacts" } } },
   {
      $set: {
         "execution.artifacts": {
            $map: {
               input: "$execution.artifacts",
               in: {
                  k: "$$this.k",
                  v: {
                     uri: {
                        $replaceOne: {
                           input: "$$this.v.uri",
                           find: "100.",
                           replacement: "200."
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $set: { "execution.artifacts": { $arrayToObject: "$execution.artifacts" } } },
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eqAHQ1DTXYb)

Perhaps you need to do some enhancements in the `$replaceOne` part. Maybe you need regular expressions or you can `$split` the string, replace one element and join the array again with `$reduce`.